# Defining a Django query set with a many-to-one relationship with calculation

Tags: python, django

I have three models: Assets, AssetTypes and Services. Assets need to get serviced every *n* months, and have a many-to-one relation with services.

```
class AssetType(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Asset Type", max_length=100)
    service_period = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Service Period (in months)", null=True, blank=True, default=12)

class Asset(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(AssetType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def service_period(self):
        return AssetType.objects.get(pk=self.type.id).service_period

    def service_history(self):
        return self.service_set.all().order_by('-date')

    def service_due_date(self):
        if self.service_period()==None:
            return None
        elif self.service_history().count()==0:
            return datetime.strptime('2017-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        else:
            last_service_date = self.service_history().latest('date').date
            return last_service_date + timedelta(self.service_period()*30)

        def service_overdue(self):
            return ((self.service_due_date()!=None) and self.service_due_date() < date.today())

class Service(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm trying to work out how to make a query set that would return a list of assets that are overdue for their service. I feel like using a model method is a red herring, and that I would be better off defining a query set filter?

I need the list of overdue assets to be a query set so I can use further query set filters on it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is unclear; none of your models have any relations with the others. Please edit to add the relationship fields. And what is `Asset.service_due_date()`?

Comment: My bad, missed the last line of the service class (which crucially had the foreign key.) and the other method.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a bit tricky.

To put the query in words, you are looking for all Assets whose latest Service date is earlier than today minus the Type's service period multiplied by 30.

To be honest, I would be tempted to denormalize this; you could add a next_service_due field on Asset which is updated when you add a new Service. Then the query is simply all assets with that field less than today.